# Is there a way to catch a windows notification event in c#?

Tags: c#, windows, notifications

Hello i'm tryng to build a program in c# that runs in background and activates when you recieve a notification in windows like a mail or a telegram message, is there a way to catch that event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Windows Service is nothing more than a Windows program which is started by the Service Control Manager (SCM). A service can be manually started or scheduled for the SCM to start immediately after user logon. If you are unfamiliar with them, you can get more information on MSDN.

I have tested the code in Visual Studio 2008 Professional SP1, .NET 3.5 SP1, Windows XP SP3. It should work on any framework above 2.0, and it just might work in 1.1. I would suggest you go through the code as you read the text as it will become a lot more clear to you.

Services have a control handler which receives all messages from Windows. These might include codes to stop or pause the service, or as in our case, device events. A managed service will abstract this control handler and give you only the `OnStart, OnStop`, and so on methods, which you can implement in order to achieve your needed functionality. We need, however, to register our own service handler, so we could catch device events. Note that this would disable all callbacks like `OnStop` except `OnStart`, which is called before we tell Windows to use our handler.

The Windows API function for this is `RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx`, which accepts a service name and a callback function to call when a message is received. We will call it in the `OnStart` function in our service. The managed version returns an `IntPtr` which is a `service handle`, but we already have a property of our class called ServiceHandle, so we don't need to save it.

The service control handler's signature is like this:

Hide   Copy Code

```
public delegate int ServiceControlHandlerEx(int control, 
                int eventType, IntPtr eventData, IntPtr context);
```

Now, we can go implement our "`OnStop`" callback by capturing the `SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP` event, which is received in the "`control`" parameter of the handler. But, in order to handle `SERVICE_CONTROL_DEVICEEVENT`, we need to do something else.

[enter link description here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32026/Capturing-Device-Events-in-a-C-Windows-Service)